# IT-Hit WebDAV Library: passing Access-Token from webapp through WebDAV-Client to webDAV-Server possible?

Tags: authentication, webdav, bearer-token, ithit-webdav-server, ithit-ajax-file-browser

I am currently working on a POC and made quite a lot of progress thanks to IT-Hit WebDAV Library.
However, I am currently stuck at the authentication. I am using the "[OnBeforeRequestSend](https://ajax.webdavsystem.com/ITHit.WebDAV.Client.WebDavSession.html#event:OnBeforeRequestSend)"-Hook to add my authentication header containing my current access-token. This approach works very well for all the request coming from my webapp.
Nevertheless, the problem I am facing right now is, that I lose the authentication-token for every request from the webdav-client...
In order to tell the webdav-client apart from any other website, I thought about using the User-Agent-Header to determine what behavior the server is going to exhibit.
To be exact: I thought about only checking the token when the user-agent is not "Microsoft Office ...".
Since this solution seems very error prone, I wanted to ask If there is another way to pass the authentication-header from my webapp through the webdav-client to the webdav-server, so that i can validate/verify every request to webdav-server independently of the source (webapp or webdav-client)?

My current stack is:

- WebApp written in TypeScript
- WebDAV-Server written in .Net

thanks and best regards,
greenbird

Answer (score 0):

Look into implementing MS-OFBA, this will work as you desire.